# Is there any way to move log analytic workspace logs in primary region to DR region log analytic workspace Azure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics-workspace, azure-regions

In Azure We have Log Analytic workspace in primary region in this law workspace both DR region and and primary region resource are connected. Now we are planning to move this DR region logs to DR region log analytic workspace. is there any possible way please help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/move-workspace-region : I have gone through this but it did not works well so expecting better results from experts

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving logs of DR region to DR LAW, you can set a new Data Collection Rule under Monitor to send new logs of DR region to RD region LAW.

When you have sufficient days logs, the old logs will be automatically deleted from that old LAW if you have set retention